# EXCEL: How do I find and match 2 different lookup values that are in separate columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vlookup

I have two tables. one with 2 columns and the other with 3 columns.
T1C1(table1&column1) have mix of T2C1 and T2C2. I need to match T1C1 with T2C1&T2C2 and return the T2C3 values to T1C2.

Here's the sample data.

[image: click the link below for the sample data]
I have tried adding `=VLOOKUP(A643,$E$643:$G$654,3,0)`
But I get #NA for ABW,ALA for all the 3 letter data.

I tried index and match but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example data, you can solve for this using the IFERROR function. I use Index/Match and table refreneces as often as possible, but the same idea applies for VLOOKUP and cell references.

[image: Two table example of iferror index match]

The table on the left is named "UserInput" and the table on the right is ISODetails. The formula I used in Column B is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ISODetails[Country ISO 2],MATCH([@[User Input]],ISODetails[Country ISO 3],0)),INDEX(ISODetails[Country ISO 2],MATCH([@[User Input]],ISODetails[Display Full],0)))
```

IFERROR checks your first formula, and if it returns "#N/A" will run the second formula. In this case, I had it check for the 3 digit code first, then check for the full name.

Here's an explanation of the formula. Sorry, this could be formatted better:

=IFERROR(INDEX(series you want to display from),MATCH(your lookup value, where you want to look for that value, 0),[if that does not work, iferror will move on to the second part]INDEX(series you want to display from),MATCH(lookup value, different column to search),0)))

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using `VLOOKUP()`, the value you are looking for is in `Column F` not `Column E` so your `VLOOKUP()` should be:

```
=VLOOKUP(A643,$F$643:$G$654,2,0)
```

Note that white space will mean `VLOOKUP()` fails. You can fix this by adding `wildcards` to your formula:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&A643&"*",$F$643:$G$654,2,0)
```